# does running two nodejs index.js with different parameters cause issues

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs bot making calls to an api, but I run it with two sets of parameters from the same directory but different terminals.  Will this cause issues for nodejs understanding how to handle the responses coming back?  Or does each bot have its own req and res?

Comment: Each bot will be making a separate request and a separate connection is established for every client so it shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: they' running in the same port? and issues of interacting to the database or what?

Comment: They are running in seperate terminals, making api calls to a web service.  port calling to would be 80 and no local database functionality.  Seems like from hdeekshith it should be fine, thanks hdeekshith